# MS SQL Server 2016 SP3 upgrade failing

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, service-pack

I tried to apply the SP3 on one of my SQL Server 2016 DB server, and it kept failing with the below error.

> Error description: The installer has encountered an unexpected error. The error code is 2203. Database: C:\WINDOWS\Installer\inprogressinstallinfo.ipi. Cannot open database file. System error -2147286928

Answer (score 1):

After trying several things, finally this worked for me: I renamed the existing C:\Temp folder to C:\Temp_old and created a new Temp folder in the C drive.

Comment: FWIW, if you do "NET HELPMSG 2203", you get "The password parameter is invalid.". I.e., likely some permission related issue with the temp folder, which is inline with how you solved the problem.